# Deleting and Moving to Project Batch Requests

Tags: vimeo-api

I have around 6000 videos that need to be either deleted or moved to a specific project. However I only get around 1000 api calls before I am rate limited. So is there any way to send, all videos to be deleted, or all videos to be moved, in a single api call?

Answer (score 0):

Batch requests are only possible on a select number of endpoints; deleting videos is not one of those endpoints. You'll need to distribute those 6000 video deletion requests over a period of time to avoid rate limit bans.

Comment: Thank you, as from the api, it is possible to add a list of videos to a project, which takes a 'comma separated list of URIs', but no matter how i Send the uris, I'm receiving a invalid parameter error.